# Have bash CLI parameter set script variable?

Tags: linux, bash, variables, parameters

I am trying to write a script such that a passed cli parameter sets a variable based on that input. The input could be multiple different options defined within the script.

Assuming these variables:

```
GROUP1 = user1 user2 
GROUP2 = user2 user3 user4
GROUP3 = user2 user5 user6
```

Running

```
./script.sh GROUP2
```

would then set the a variable called GROUP = user2 user3 user4.

I would like the above command to be able to set a variable called 'GROUP' equal to one of the defined variables based on the passed cli parameter.

I believe that this can be achieved via parameter substitution, but I have not been able to figure out how. Still new to bash scripting, so any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean variable indirection (see man bash):

```
#!/bin/bash
GROUP1="user1 user2"
GROUP2="user2 user3 user4"
GROUP3="user2 user5 user6"
echo ${!1}

$ script.sh GROUP2
user2 user3 user4
```

Be also careful with quotes and spaces.